# VS 2019 and older versions of TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

What versions of TFS does Visual Studio 2019 work with? At work we're still on TFS 2015. I'm concerned that might be too old to work with VS 2019.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio 2019 works with Azure DevOps Server 2019, TFS 2017, TFS 2015, TFS 2013, TFS 2012 and TFS 2010 SP1.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/compatibility#team-explorer-azure-devops-server-and-team-foundation-server

I assume it works with TFS 2018 as well, even it is not mentioned in the article.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian! The link gives me other useful information, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Visual studio 2019 
use TFS 2019 (New name: Azure DevOps Server 2019)  update 1.1 for server

And local you do not need install anything just use VS 2019
[Download SERVER TFS Update 1.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/now-available-azure-devops-server-2019-update-1-1-rc-2/)